# Question about amp-analytics dynamic tracking

Tags: amp-html

I'm using amp-analytics to track data sending to my own end point. How can I track which button or link the user clicked? I tried adding data-vars-* attribute for the elements I'm tracking click for, but it turns out that the result only shows the first element I clicked correctly.

For example I have multiple elements that can have click action, for any click I want to trigger a pageAction event.

html:

```
      <button class="trackedAction" data-vars-event-category="page button" data-vars-event-target="toggle article" data-vars-event-label="Show/Hide Article">a button</button>

      <amp-carousel ...>
          <amp-img ... class="trackedAction" data-vars-event-category="image" data-vars-event-target="./img-01" data-vars-event-label="ai-img-01"></amp-img>
          <amp-img ... class="trackedAction" data-vars-event-category="image" data-vars-event-target="./img-02" data-vars-event-label="ai-img-02"></amp-img>
          <amp-img ... class="trackedAction" data-vars-event-category="image" data-vars-event-target="./img-03" data-vars-event-label="ai-img-03"></amp-img>
      </amp-carousel>

      <form ...
        data-vars-event-target="https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/submit-form-input-text-xhr">
          <input ...
           class="trackedAction" data-vars-event-category="input" data-vars-event-target="input" data-vars-event-label="form input">
          <input ...
           class="trackedAction" data-vars-event-category="input" data-vars-event-target="input" data-vars-event-label="form input">
          <input ... class="trackedAction" data-vars-event-category="submit" data-vars-event-target="submit" data-vars-event-label="form submit">
      </form>
```

As indicated from the code, I have multiple elements grouped in class "trackedAction", but when I trigger the event with click, the result only shows the first element's info. Eg. If I click img-01 first, every other elements show the same event category, event target, event label the same as img-01.

amp-analytics:

```
 <amp-analytics config="...">
      <script type="application/json">
        {
          ...
          "triggers": {
            "trackPageAction": {
              "on": "click",
              "selector": ".trackedAction",
              "request": "event"
            }
          }
        }
      </script>
 </amp-analytics>
```

Any idea why this happens? thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried in this way `<amp-analytics config="..."><script type="application/json">{ ... "triggers": {"trackPageAction": {"on": "click","selector": ".trackedAction", "vars": {  "event-category": "${eventCategory}","event-target": "${eventTarget}","event-label":"${eventlabel}" }}}}</script></amp-analytics>`